# Counting how many times a number appear in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame and a dictionary of lists. The dataframe looks like:

```
Name     begin    stop    ID      
Peter     30       150    1      
Hugo     4500     6000    2      
Jennie    300      700    3
```

The dictionary looks like:

```
dictionary = {'0':[30,60,4650],'1':[100,5971]}
```

I want to create a new dataframe where I go through each of the list in a dictionary and see which interval (specified by begin column and stop column) does the value fall. For example 30, 60, and 100 falls in the the first row and 4650 and 5971 in dictionary falls in second row. But none of the values fall in third row. So I want to create a new dataframe such that I add the count as well. So the new dataframe looks like:

```
Name     begin    stop    ID    count   
Peter     30       150    1      3
Hugo     4500     6000    2      2
Jennie    300      700    3      0
```

How can I achieve this? Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
df["count"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: sum(
        x["begin"] <= i <= x["stop"] for v in dictionary.values() for i in v
    ),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Name  begin  stop  ID  count
0   Peter     30   150   1      3
1    Hugo   4500  6000   2      2
2  Jennie    300   700   3      0
```

---

EDIT: Alternative solution using `bisect`:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

dictionary = {"0": [30, 60, 4650], "1": [100, 5971]}
values = sorted([v for lst in dictionary.values() for v in lst])

df["count"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: bisect_left(values, x["stop"]) - bisect_left(values, x["begin"]),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Name  begin  stop  ID  count
0   Peter     30   150   1      3
1    Hugo   4500  6000   2      2
2  Jennie    300   700   3      0
```

Comment: This seems to take a very long time. I have 100383 enteries in my dataframe. Is it possible to make it faster?

Comment: It kept on running for 5 hours and then my notebook crashed.

Comment: Yes I have 150 columns.

Comment: I have 100 keys and for each key I have 500 values in list.

Comment: @John Well, that's a problem... each row needs to be checked with `500*100` values. So `100k*500*100`, thats `5_000_000_000` checks...

Comment: @John I try to come up with faster solution.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured. But do you think using mutiple cores would help?

Comment: Thank you @Andrej. I shall wait for you reply

Comment: @John Try my updated answer, should be faster.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.